# How to append the unsorted elements at the end of the array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort the array elements as below:

```
let defaultOrder = [
    {'item': 'Pen', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Spike', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Pencil', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Ink', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Mail', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Rubber', 'value': '5'}
];

let items = [
    {'item': 'Spike', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Duck', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Ink', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Pencil', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Rubber', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Mail', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Pen', 'value': '5'} 
];

let orderedItems = items.sort(function (a,b){
    return defaultOrder.indexOf(a.item) - defaultOrder.indexOf(b.item)
});
```

I am able to sort the elements, but how to make the unsorted elements, from above: `{'item': 'Duck', 'value': '5'}`, to get appended at the very end of the sorted items?

Comment: What do you mean by "unsorted"? The item you specified is included in the ordered items.

Comment: `defaultOrder.indexOf(a.item)` won't work. `a.item` is a string. the elements of `defaultOrder` are objects. You need `defaultOrder.findIndex(el => el.item == a.item)`

Comment: @mykaf I think they mean items that aren't in `defaultOrder`, like `Duck`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for the positions and a default value for unknown items.

```js
const
    defaultOrder = [{ item: 'Pen', value: '5' }, { item: 'Spike', value: '5' }, { item: 'Pencil', value: '5' }, { item: 'Ink', value: '5' }, { item: 'Mail', value: '5' }, { item: 'Rubber', value: '5' }],
    order = Object.fromEntries(defaultOrder.map(({ item }, index) => [item, index + 1])),
    items = [{ item: 'Spike', value: '5' }, { item: 'Duck', value: '5' }, { item: 'Ink', value: '5' }, { item: 'Pencil', value: '5' }, { item: 'Rubber', value: '5' }, { item: 'Mail', value: '5' }, { item: 'Pen', value: '5' }];

items.sort((a, b) => (order[a.item] || Infinity) - (order[b.item] || Infinity));

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if an item isn't found in `defaultOrder`, and return an appropriate value so it will sort at the end.

```js
let defaultOrder = [
    {'item': 'Pen', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Spike', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Pencil', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Ink', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Mail', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Rubber', 'value': '5'}
];

let items = [
    {'item': 'Spike', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Duck', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Ink', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Pencil', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Rubber', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Mail', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Pen', 'value': '5'} 
];

let orderedItems = items.sort(function (a,b){
    let aPos = defaultOrder.findIndex(el => el.item == a.item);
    let bPos = defaultOrder.findIndex(el => el.item == b.item);
    if (aPos == -1) {
      return 1;
    } else if (bPos == -1) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return aPos - bPos;
    }
});

console.log(orderedItems);
```

Comment: It's not specifically stated in the question as a requirement (and in this specific case, will never occur if the `.item` property is unique), but the way that you've implemented it is not a [stable sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#sort_stability)

Comment: Yes, sorry, 'item' is not unique, we may get repeated values for item.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that is to check if exactly one of those is not found in the `defaultOrder` array, then return `1` to `-1` to signify the order.

Additionally, you need to use `Array.prototype.findIndex` to find an object with that property. Originally, you were searching for the string `'Pen'` (for example) instead of an object that has the `.item` property as `'Pen'`

```js
let defaultOrder = [
    {'item': 'Pen', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Spike', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Pencil', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Ink', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Mail', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Rubber', 'value': '5'}
];

let items = [
    {'item': 'Spike', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Duck', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Ink', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Pencil', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Rubber', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Mail', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Pen', 'value': '5'} 
];

let orderedItems = items.sort(function (a,b){
    let aIndex = defaultOrder.findIndex((other) => other.item === a.item);
    let bIndex = defaultOrder.findIndex((other) => other.item === b.item);
    
    if (aIndex === bIndex) return 0;
    if (aIndex === -1) return 1;
    if (bIndex === -1) return -1;
    return aIndex - bIndex;
});

console.log(orderedItems);
```

```css
/* fill the screen on Stack Overflow */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `Array::sort()` since you have already a sorted order in the first array (so use an already known information to your advantagle).

1. Get already sorted indices from the first array by item names
2. Build a new array with the indices map + put not found items to the end (after the sorted array length):

```js
let defaultOrder = ['Pen', 'Spike', 'Pencil', 'Ink', 'Mail', 'Rubber']

let items = [
    {'item': 'Spike', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Duck', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Ink', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Pencil', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Rubber', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Mail', 'value': '5'}, 
    {'item': 'Pen', 'value': '5'} 
];

const indices = {};
defaultOrder.forEach((item, index) => indices[item] = index);

const result = Array(items.length);
let unsortedPos = defaultOrder.length;
for(const item of items){
  result[indices[item.item] ?? unsortedPos++] = item;
}


console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is beautiful! If you don't mind, can you please provide some tech details on the `reduce` function? I am trying to get my head around so I can solve these array operations in a more productive way. TIA.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. i've removed `reduce` and made the index map contruction simpler

Comment: In a scenario where the `defaultOrder = ['Pen', 'Spike', 'Pencil', 'Ink', 'Mail', 'Rubber' ];`, can we use `reduce` to improve the performance?

Comment: @ArnoldJr. `reduce` is the same as the more simple approach i've changed it to

Comment: I am trying to use `defaultOrder = ['Pen', 'Spike', 'Pencil', 'Ink', 'Mail', 'Rubber' ];`, but seems like I am getting some empty elements. 
If you don't mind, can you update the detaultOrder in you snippet?

Comment: @ArnoldJr. sorry, but this algorithm wouldn't work in the `item` isn't unique ‍♂️